# oracle pl-sql find the 3rd wednesday of a given date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

Currently I have a process which takes a date variable EG: '01-MAR-2026', it then iterates over this date checking if the day is wednesday. If so then increment a counter else add 1 day and check again.
This exits when the wednesday count is = 3.

```
IF (to_char(v_Date,'dy') = 'wed') THEN
        v_NumWed := v_NumWed + 1;
END IF;

WHILE (v_NumWed != 3) LOOP
    v_Date := v_Date + interval '1' day;
    IF (to_char(v_Date, 'dy') = 'wed') THEN
        v_NumWed := v_NumWed + 1;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

However I have a feeling there is a simpler way to achieve this maybe via a query or something not using a loop EG: use an input date and query to find the first wednesday then + 14 days?

Any suggestions would be great, thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I have something like this which appears to work, also considers if the first day is a wednesday itself.

```
select next_day(trunc(v_date, 'MM') - 1, 'WED'), next_day(trunc(v_date, 'MM') - 1, 'WED') + 14 into v_first, v_third from dual;
```

SOLVED: thanks for the help folks, got a few possible solutions now in the comments!

Comment: So for 2026-03-01 you're expecting result 2026-03-18, right? What if the original date is itself a Wednesday - should 2026-03-04 also map to 2026-03-18, or 2026-03-25?

Comment: Alex - good test case, I think the edited code at the bottom covers it. 01-APR-20 is a wednesday and goes into v_first. the 15th is the 3rd wednesday and goes into v_third. Not essentially graceful looking but it works

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Find the first Wednesday (using `NEXT_DAY`) that follows some date, and add 14 days (i.e. 2 weeks) to find the 3rd Wednesday.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH test (col)
  2       AS (SELECT DATE '2020-01-27' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT DATE '2020-02-06' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT DATE '2020-02-12' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT col, NEXT_DAY (col, 'wed') + 14 next_3
  8    FROM test;

COL        NEXT_3
---------- ----------
27.01.2020 12.02.2020
06.02.2020 26.02.2020
12.02.2020 04.03.2020

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If comment you posted means that - for any date - you want to find 3rd Wednesday in that month, then truncate date to *month* (which returns 1st day in that month) and find the 3rd Wednesday, taking care about whether the 1st day of the month is (or is not) Wednesday.

```
SQL> WITH test (col)
  2       AS (SELECT DATE '2020-01-27' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT DATE '2020-02-06' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT DATE '2020-03-18' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT col,
  8           NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (col, 'mm'), 'wed')
  9         + CASE
 10              WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (col, 'mm'), 'dy') = 'wed' THEN 7
 11              ELSE 14
 12           END
 13            next_3
 14    FROM test;

COL        NEXT_3
---------- ----------
27.01.2020 15.01.2020
06.02.2020 19.02.2020
18.03.2020 18.03.2020

SQL>
```

Comment: goal is 3rd wednesday of a month starting from the 1st of that month, can't spill over into next month EG: not a rolling every 3rd wednesday :)

Comment: Aha; so, depending on date, you want to find 3rd Wednesday in that month. I edited my answer and added some more code. See if it helps.

Comment: yeh that was my bad sorry, that new code looks pretty good I'll have a play around withat as well, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

TO get the third Wednesday from a date, including that date if ti is itself a Wednesday, you can do:

```
select next_day(date '2026-03-01' + 13, 'Wednesday') from dual;

NEXT_DAY(D
----------
2026-03-18
```

The `next_day` function is a bit awkward because it is NLS-sensitive, and doesn't have an override (like `to_char()` does) - so the NLS session language and the day name/abbreviation have to be in the same language. If you can't control then then you can work around it by getting the current-language day-name from a known fixed date:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'French';

select to_char(date '2026-03-01', 'Day'),
  next_day(date '2026-03-01' + 13, to_char(date '1999-12-29', 'Day'))
from dual;

TO_CHAR( NEXT_DAY(D
-------- ----------
Dimanche 2026-03-18
```

Demo with some sample dates:

```
with t (sample_date) as (
  select date '2026-02-15' + level
  from dual
  connect by level <= 31
)
select sample_date, next_day(sample_date + 13, 'Wednesday') as third_wed
from t
order by sample_date;

SAMPLE_DAT THIRD_WED 
---------- ----------
2026-02-16 2026-03-04
2026-02-17 2026-03-04
2026-02-18 2026-03-04
2026-02-19 2026-03-11
2026-02-20 2026-03-11
2026-02-21 2026-03-11
2026-02-22 2026-03-11
2026-02-23 2026-03-11
2026-02-24 2026-03-11
2026-02-25 2026-03-11
2026-02-26 2026-03-18
2026-02-27 2026-03-18
2026-02-28 2026-03-18
2026-03-01 2026-03-18
2026-03-02 2026-03-18
2026-03-03 2026-03-18
2026-03-04 2026-03-18
2026-03-05 2026-03-25
2026-03-06 2026-03-25
2026-03-07 2026-03-25
2026-03-08 2026-03-25
2026-03-09 2026-03-25
2026-03-10 2026-03-25
2026-03-11 2026-03-25
2026-03-12 2026-04-01
2026-03-13 2026-04-01
2026-03-14 2026-04-01
2026-03-15 2026-04-01
2026-03-16 2026-04-01
2026-03-17 2026-04-01
2026-03-18 2026-04-01
```

Comment: thanks Alex, realized I should have explained the data set a bit more.
the start day will always be 01, the month will always be either Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec but the year can be any year from current onwards

Comment: @C-MATT - this still works, doesn't it? You'll just won't encounter most of the dates. That really isn't what your question says, but your approach should be OK too; though the `trunc()` looks a bit pointless, and you can do +13 still instead of -1 + 14. Same basic idea.

Comment: seen your updates, forgot about the NLS_ impact... original code check the day of week = 4 which only works for USA as their day 1 is sunday so day 4 is wednesday. this code will be run globally potentially so the oracle nls_database settings are set to America for territory, language and date language. do you think that is ok

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved the issue, just wanted to show you another example:

```
DECLARE
        dStartDate DATE := SYSDATE;
        dNextWednesDay DATE;
BEGIN
        FOR n IN 1..3 LOOP
                dNextWednesDay := NEXT_DAY(dStartDate, 'WEDNESDAY');
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dNextWednesDay);

                dStartDate := dNextWednesDay +1;
        END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

Output:

```
2020-02-19 15:33:58
2020-02-26 15:33:58
2020-03-04 15:33:58
```